# Adding timeouts for a method executing multiple paths

Tags: java, recursion, timeout

I have the following method definition

```
   private void pollForStatus() throws  InterruptedException {

            if (state.equals("running")) {
                log.debug("Task still running, Polling again ..");
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                pollForStatus();
            }

            else if (state.equals("complete") ) {
                return;
            }

            else if (state.equals("stopped")) {
            {
                    // Report error state

            }

}
```

Now in order that this 'pllForStatus' does not keep executing in certain situations, I want to add a timeout for the recursion. How is this achieved in Java (7)?

Comment: isnt recursion supposed to work toward a base case?

Comment: The base case being if the 'state' changes in the above case correct? I was thinking more in terms of if for some reason the state gets stuck in the 'running' state causing the recursion to recurse indefinitely

Comment: one approach would b to record the time the thread starts using System.currentTimeMillis, then calculate a future time, and on each loop, make sure the futureTime hasnt passed. Something to that effect

Comment: Should I be comparing time before the recursive call?

Comment: yep. Il update my answer with a code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis + yourInterval;
private void pollForStatus() throws InterruptedException {

    if (state.equals("running")) {
        log.debug("Task still running, Polling again ..");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);

        //havnt reached cut off time yet, loop again
        if(System.currentTimeMilis() < futureTime){
            pollForStatus();
        }
    } else if (state.equals("complete")) {
        return;
    } else if (state.equals("stopped")) {

        // Report error state

    }


}
```